# Adjointness of Hom and Tensor for non commutative ring

Tags: tensor-products, noncommutative-algebra

Let $M$ be an $(A,B)$-bimodule, let $N$ be a $(B,C)$-bimodule, and let $K$ be an $(A,C)$-bimodule. Then $$\operatorname{Hom}_C(M \otimes_{B}N,K) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_B(M,\operatorname{Hom}_C(N,K))$$ as right $A$-modules, and $$\operatorname{Hom}_A(M\otimes_B N,K) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_B(N,\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,K))$$ as right $C$-modules.

Where  can I get a proof for this? I tried to do. But I am not able to complete.

Comment: Where exactly do you get stuck?

Comment: obviously, you would find such a proof e.g. in bourbaki, Algebra III

Comment: I started with a map $ f \in \operatorname{Hom}_C(M \otimes_{B}N,K)$. then defined a map $\theta (x)(y)=f(x \otimes y)$ for $x \in M$ and $y \in N$. How can I prove that the map $ \theta$ is right B linear so that   $\theta \in \operatorname{Hom}_B(M,\operatorname{Hom}_C(N,K))$.

Comment: @AnupamAh Ok, I'll edit my answer to include those details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't very much that you can do except the obvious thing:

Define a map $$f:\operatorname{Hom}_C(M \otimes_{B}N,K) \to \operatorname{Hom}_B(M,\operatorname{Hom}_C(N,K))$$
by $f(\phi) = (m \mapsto (n \mapsto \phi(m \otimes n)))$. Check that this is well-defined, i.e., that $f(\phi)$ really is a homomorphism of right $B$-modules.$^{(*)}$

Conversely, define a map $$\operatorname{Hom}_C(M \otimes_{B}N,K) \leftarrow \operatorname{Hom}_B(M,\operatorname{Hom}_C(N,K)):g$$
by $g(\psi) = (m \otimes n \mapsto \psi(m)(n))$. Check that this is well-defined using the universal property of the tensor product.

Then $$f(g(\psi))(m) = (n \mapsto g(\psi)(m \otimes n) = \psi(m)(n)) = \psi(m)$$
and $$g(f(\phi))(m \otimes n) = f(\phi)(m)(n) = \phi(m \otimes n),$$

which proves that $f,g$ are mutual inverses.

---

$^{(*)}$ Let's prove this. The subtlety lies in the definitions of the different module structures on Hom sets. We need to recall that the $(A,B)$-bimodule structure on $\operatorname{Hom}_C(N,K)$ is given by $$a \cdot \kappa \cdot b:n \mapsto a\kappa(bn). \tag{1}$$
And also, the right $A$-module structure on $\operatorname{Hom}_B(M,\operatorname{Hom}_C(N,K))$ is given by $$\psi \cdot a: m \mapsto \psi(a m). \tag{2}$$

For the domain, the tensor product $M \otimes_B N$ is an $(A,C)$-bimodule via $$a \cdot (m \otimes n) \cdot c = (am \otimes nc), \tag{3}$$ and $\operatorname{Hom}_C(M \otimes_{B}N,K)$ becomes a right $A$-module via $$(\phi \cdot a)(m \otimes n) = a(m \otimes n) = am \otimes n. \tag{4}$$

---

Okay. First, to check that $f(\phi)$ is a homomorphism of right $B$-modules:
$$\begin{align}f(\phi)(m + m'b)(n) &= \phi(m + m'b \otimes n) \\&= \phi(m \otimes n) + \phi(m'b \otimes n) \\&=\phi(m \otimes n) + \phi(m' \otimes bn) 
\\&=f(\phi)(m)(n) + (f(\phi)(m')\cdot b)(n) \tag{1 and 3}
\\&=(f(\phi)(m) + (f(\phi)(m')\cdot b))(n).
\end{align}$$

Next, to check that $f$ is a homomorphism of right $A$-modules:
$$\begin{align}
f(\phi + \phi' \cdot a)(m)(n) &= (\phi + \phi' \cdot a)(m \otimes n) \\ &=
\phi(m \otimes n) + (\phi'\cdot a)(m \otimes n) \\ &=
\phi(m \otimes n) + \phi'(am \otimes n)\tag{4} \\
&= f(\phi)(m)(n) + (f(\phi') \cdot a)(m)(n) \tag{2}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: I stuck in checking that $f(\phi)$ is right B linear. To check this we want to prove that $f(\phi)(mb+m')=f(\phi)(m).b+f(\phi)(m')$. Here I stuck. $f(\phi)(mb+m')(n)= \phi((mb+m') \otimes n)= \phi((mb \otimes n+m' \otimes n)=\phi((mb \otimes n)+ \phi((m' \otimes n)$. How to proceed further?

Comment: $M \otimes_{B}N$ is A-C bimodule and $K$ is also a A-C bimodule and so both $M \otimes_{B}N$ and $K$ are right C linear modules.  $\operatorname{Hom}_C(M \otimes_{B}N,K)$ consists of all right C linear module homomorphisms between $M \otimes_{B}N$ and $K$. Am i right? Does an element of $\operatorname{Hom}_C(M \otimes_{B}N,K)$ any more property?

Comment: @AnupamAh I edited in the details for $f$.

Comment: Can I ask you one more doubt. What is the exact universal property of tensor product of Bimodules. As far as I know it states that If M is an A-B bimodule and N is an B-C bimodule and $ M \otimes_{B}N$ is the A-C bimodule and for any A-C bimodule K and any bilinear(in A and C) and  B balanced map there exists a unique bimodule homomorphism from  $ M \otimes_{B}N$  to K. Am i right?

Comment: I stuck in proving the well definedness of the map g as u said. I am not sure about the way of doing it. What I think to do is to first define a map $M \times N$ to $K$ by $ (x,y) \rightarrow f(x)(y)$ for $f \in \operatorname{Hom}_B(M,\operatorname{Hom}_C(N,K))$. Then by the universal property there exists a  unique map from $M \otimes_{B}N$  to K.

Comment: @AnupamAh I was just thinking about the usual universal property for tensor products with values in Abelian groups, namely: you check that your map $(m,n) \mapsto \psi(m)(n)$ is $B$-balanced, and hence it induces the well-defined Abelian group homomorphism $m \otimes n \mapsto \psi(m)(n)$. Then you can simply check by hand that this in in fact right $C$-linear, hence it belongs to $\operatorname{Hom}_C(M \otimes_B N,K)$. But yes, there might be some more general bimodule property you can invoke.

Comment: @ Alex Provost Thank you so much for your help, I could prove it completely. Thanks again:)